# ¿Cómo recuperar registros de una API rest con Angular 4?

Tags: angular

Tengo problemas con las peticiones get y post en Angular 4. Soy nueva utilizando éste framework y es mi interés aprender a recuperar e insertar registros desde una API.

¿Alguien podría decirme cuál es el procedimiento para hacerlo?

Gracias.

```
  getUsuario(usuario, contrasena) {
    this.http.post('http://123.456.78.90:12345/api/IniciarSesion', {
      NombreUsuario: usuario,
      Password: contrasena
    })
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        if(res.Usuario === null)
          alert('Usuario o contraseña incorrectos');
        else if (res.Usuario.IdUsuario>0)
          alert('Usuario autenticado');
      },
      err => {
        console.log('Error occured');
      }
    );
```

Ese es el código que he intentado hasta ahora y me marca un error en 'Usuario'. Cabe mencionar que descargué un ejemplo de internet y técnicamente debería funcionar. Lo que no entiendo es el porqué del error. No sé si falte declarar algún servicio o no sé. Cabe mencionar que a la API a la que tiene acceso está hecha con C# y SQL Server.

Comment: coloca el codigo que has intentado hasta el momento para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ya lo agregué. También paso el código que he intentado para el método get (el de arriba es post, aunque se llame get) y me marca un error en lo siguiente:   this.http.get('http://123.456.78.90:12345/api/Usuarios/BusquedaUsuarios/{IdCliente}/{IdFuerzaVenta}/{Distrito}/{Ruta}/{IdUsuario}/{NombreUsuario}',
     {params: Params})
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.listaUsuarios = data.Data;
       this.ocultarListaUsuarios = false;
       //console.log(data);
    });

Comment: Me marca un error en: this.listaUsuarios=data.Data. ¿A qué crees que se deba?

Comment: @Yarizza indica el mensaje del error, ya que esto nos facilita en la ayuda.

Comment: Sólo me indica que 'Usuario' no existe en éste contexto. Lo mismo pasa con 'Data'. No sé si sea algún tipo de palabra reservada, porque ya estuve buscando en internet, sin éxito.

Comment: ¿De qué clase es el atributo `this.http`?

Answer (score 0):

A ver, creo que el error es por clases.

**Que ocurre?**

Cuando intenta utilizar esta comparación **`res.Usuario === null`**, tienes un objecto en el proyecto con esa propiedad? No funciona igual que Javscript normal, tienes que **`parsearlo`** a un objeto para poder acceder.

**Backend**

Tengo que suponer que la **`API`** te devuelve un objecto de C#, con mayúsculas por ejemplo, por lo que tienes que parsearlo a un objeto de **Typescript**, digamos que esta clase me devuelve un usuario y contraseña.

Un ejemplo de la clase en C#:

```
public class User {
      public string Username { get; set; }
      public string Password { get; set; }
   }
```

Ahora cuando vamos a hacer el **`post`** a la **`API`** tenemos que enviarle los parámetros para esas propiedades, ya que es lo que probablemente tengas programado que te pida, como por ejemplo:

```
public async Task<User> IniciarSesion([FromUri] User user) {
            /// ...... Aquí tu logica
        }
```

**Frontend**

Como habiamos dicho antes, tienes que parsear tu objeto de C# a uno de Typescript, asi que creamos una clase **`User`**:

```
export class User {
  name: string;
  password: string;

  constructor() {}

  static deserialize(item: any): User {
    const user = new User();

    user.name = item.Username;
    user.password = item.Password;

    return user;
  }
}
```

Ahora cuando haces la petición y te devuelve **`res`**, puedes hacer un **`deserialize`** ya que admite cualquier tipo de objeto y devuelve un objecto que conocemos(**`user`**).

```
 getUsuario(usuario, contrasena) {
         this.http.post('http://123.456.78.90:12345/api/IniciarSesion', {
                 Username: usuario,
                 Password: contrasena
             })
             .subscribe(
                 res => {
                     console.log(res);

                     const users = User.deserialize(res);
                     if (user == null) {
                         alert('Usuario o contraseña incorrectos');
                     } else {
                         alert('Error occured');
                     }
                 },
                 err => {
                     console.log('Error occured');
                 }
             );
```

Fíjate que también he cambiado el método **`this.http.post`**.

No te olvides de poner le **`import`** arriba!

`import { User} from "../model/user";`

Te recomiendo abrir otra pregunta y buscar mejores técnicas para utilizar una API, así como lo estas haciendo es bastante inseguro, deberías de utilizar **hasing** y dar **tokens**, pero si estas aprendiendo esta bien!